# Express 4 router.param doesnt fire

Tags: node.js, express

I have a node express 4 app and I want to mount a route (contacts) on a parent route. i.e

```
/:fundid/contacts
```

In my fund route I declare

```
var router = require('express').Router({ mergeParams: true });

var contactRoutes = require('./contacts');
router.use('/:fundid/contacts', contactRoutes);
```

In my contact route

```
var router = require('express').Router({ mergeParams: true });

router.param('fundid', function(res, req, next, id){});
```

The problem is that this param call does not fire. From what I can garner from the documentation these param calls are relative to the router they are declared on, but i would have thought mergeParams:true would affect this, but it doesn't. The route is otherwise working, and both routes are called. Am I missing something?

The reason I want to do this is because I want to mount the contacts route on multiple parent routes, and build a filter based on those parent parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This comment](https://github.com/strongloop/express/issues/2138#issuecomment-44147565) suggests that parameters are tied to the router they are declared with; so in your case, `fundid` can only be handled by the "fund" router. `mergeParams` serves a different purpose, namely to provide access to `req.params.fundid` from child routers.

You can always use a request middleware in your contact router to perform special operations based on the fundid, though:

```
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var id = req.params.fundid;
  ...
});
```

Comment: That's exactly what I've done. I wonder why it behaves this way? I would have thought that the param call would happen if the parameter is present regardless..thanks btw!

Comment: @ojf apparently, it's a design choice to call `param()` on the router for which the parameter is declared in a route.